# Conflict on the React ant design table input total balance

Tags: antd, react-typescript

Im tried to do some calculate  part for my react ant design 4 table, i don't have idea for how to get when i entered value after get automatically calculate total  and then submit. any onw know how to do that correctly.

Thanks

**[stack blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-usdpft-6d9vlu?file=index.js)**

**This is my code part**

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    key: 'name',
    render: text => <a>{text}</a>,
  },
  {
    title: 'Book',
    dataIndex: 'book',
    key: 'book',
  },
  {
    title: 'Pen',
    dataIndex: 'pen',
    key: 'pen',
  },
  {
    title: 'Tools',
    key: 'tools',
    dataIndex: 'tools',

  },
  {
    title: 'Total',
    key: 'total',
       dataIndex: 'total',
  },
];

const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    book: <Form.Item name="book1"  rules={[{required: true, message: " is required"}]}><Input style={{width: 150}}/></Form.Item>,
    pen: <Form.Item name="oen1"  rules={[{required: true, message: "is required"}]}><Input style={{width: 150}}/></Form.Item>,
   tools: <Form.Item name="tools1"  rules={[{required: true, message: " is required"}]}><Input style={{width: 150}}/></Form.Item>,
   total:'00000'
  },

];
 const onFinish = values => {
    console.log(values);
  };
ReactDOM.render( 
  <div> 
    <Form name="control-hooks" onFinish={onFinish}>
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
      <div>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </div>
    </Form>
  </div>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed the rows can be more than one. You can achieve this by:

1. You need a state. In react, in order to change something on the UI (e.g. total column) you need a state. Put your data array in state.

   const [data, setData] = useState([ ... ])
2. You need to know which row the input was when you type in. You may add some distinction on input that is equal to row key. Here I suggest to put some number on the name of input:

   <Form.Item name="book-1">...</Form.Item>

   <Form.Item name="pen-1">...</Form.Item>

   <Form.Item name="tools-1">...</Form.Item>
3. Use `onValuesChange` prop of the `<Form>` it triggers every time you type on the inputs and return the form values. With this, you can extract the number on input name and use that as a reference to know which row is about to change and perform setState.

I also suggest to use InputNumber instead of Input if you only need a number input.

Here is the [working link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-usdpft-zqxt6z). You can start/play around there if I did not hit what you want.

You may also look on [antd table editable rows](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-row). This might be easiest to use than this